# map Function does not return without using return keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. While studying it I came across map function. The guy was making a quiz app and used map to iterate over an answers array as:

```
{this.state.allQuestions[this.state.currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
                      <button onClick={() => this.handleAnswerOptionClick(answerOption.isCorrect)}>{answerOption.answerText}</button>
                    ))}
//allQuestions is an array which contains question as well as an array of its options (answerOptions).
```

While I am using the same method to iterate over a normal array I do not get the desired result, unless I use return statement. Here is my code:

```
function Component() {
      const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Component</h1>
          {arr.map((item) => {
            <button>{item}</button> //does not return anything
            //return <button>{item}</button>  Gives the output
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Why is that return is required here but not in the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of function you (and the quiz) uses is called an *arrow function*. Arrow function have some benefits, one of which being that you can *sometimes* omit the `return` keyword.

According to the MDN ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)):

> One param. With simple expression return is not needed:
>
> ```
> param => expression
> ```

and

> Multiline statements require body brackets and return:
>
> ```
> param => {
>   let a = 1;
>   return a + param;
> }
> ```

---

To answer your question - the reason it does not work in your code is because you are trying to do the 2nd method shown above (using curly braces, which require `return`), whereas the quiz uses the first syntax (where `return` is not needed).